# Visual Studio 2022 hangs when I try to add an Entity Framework datamodel

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, ef-database-first

When I try to add an Entity Framework data model (database-first) to my project, I get this warning and Visual Studio hangs

[image: Error]

Comment: Here's the more modern workflow with EF Core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're encountering a problem when trying to add a Entity Framework data model (database first) to your project. The warning you're seeing may be related to the version of Entity Framework that you're using, or it could be caused by an issue with your Visual Studio installation.Try updating your visual studio and entity framework to the latest version, if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

This error is mostly due to version conflicts. If you are sure that the framework you introduced is fine, please follow the steps below:

TOOLS===>Options===>Text Templating ===>show security message will be false not true